# php breaking my Media Gallery wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been digging through every line of code deleting, commenting, and checking until I reached these lines of code:

```
/* Retrieve Shortcodes
* @see http://fwp.drewsymo.com/shortcodes/
*/

$foundation_shortcodes = trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . 'inc/shortcodes.php';

if (file_exists($foundation_shortcodes)) {
require( $foundation_shortcodes );
}
```

When deleted/commented, the media gallery will display the images. When it's live, the media gallery won't work. I've checked every other possibility, plugins, the code inside of the shortcodes.php file (deleted everything out of the file and tested), but the above code is breaking something. What's wrong?

I'm not much of a php guy, what's wrong with this code? It must be partially right, because it pulls the shortcodes.php content in, and the shortcodes work on page.

(code inside of functions.php)

Answer (score 0):

If the gallery works when this code is removed it suggests that the code being added in the shortcodes.php file is what is causing your issue.

Examine the code in that file.

Before you do that though you may want to watch the php error log too.  This will likely give you the exact location of the error.

Comment: I deleted everything from the shortcode file, and the behavior was the same.